# showing datepicker 18 years back and lock the ui datepicker in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In my project i need to show the date picker 18 back and i need to lock the 80 years backs so how can i show those date in datepicker can any one help me to find  here
here am adding code my code i printed in log but i need to display on my datepicker so how can i display

```
NSCalendar * gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate * currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents * comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setYear: -18];
NSDate * minDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents: comps toDate: currentDate options: 0];
[comps setYear: -100];
NSDate * maxDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents: comps toDate: currentDate options: 0];
[comps release];

self.datePickerView.minimumDate = minDate;
self.datePickerView.maximumDate = maxDate;

NSLog(@"minDate   %@", minDate);
NSLog(@"maxDate%@", maxDate);
```

Answer (score 20):

Hi first of all minimum date must be 100 year back date and max date must be 18 year back date and then set pickerView's date to a date between range of dates so your final code will be looks like

```
NSCalendar * gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate * currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents * comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setYear: -18];
NSDate * maxDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents: comps toDate: currentDate options: 0];
[comps setYear: -100];
NSDate * minDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents: comps toDate: currentDate options: 0];
[comps release];

self.datePickerView.minimumDate = minDate;
self.datePickerView.maximumDate = maxDate;
self.datePickerView.date = minDate;
```

Hopefully this will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek Kumar for fast replay i tried with your code but date was not showing in uidatepicker ..in console it is showing like this

2012-10-12 15:20:39.363 Blood[4398:207] minDate 1912-10-12 09:27:19 +0000 2012-10-12 15:20:39.364 Blood[4398:207] maxDate1994-10-12 09:50:39 +0000

Answer (score 2):

Here is viewDidLoad method of view controller class

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    NSCalendar * gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDate * currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents * comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [comps setYear: -18];
    NSDate * maxDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents: comps toDate: currentDate options: 0];
    [comps setYear: -100];
    NSDate * minDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents: comps toDate: currentDate options: 0];
    [comps release];



    UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];
    [pickerView setMinimumDate:minDate];
    [pickerView setMaximumDate:maxDate];
    [pickerView setDate:minDate];
    [[self view] addSubview:pickerView];

}
```

**My Output is**

[image]

can  you please share your output as screenshot ?

Comment: i tried but i didnt get any thing.its not locking its showing all previous years!! am unable attach screen shot stack does not accept to attaching image to me.in date picker its showing normal current date only

Comment: did you try my code ? i created datepicker from code also try this and hopefully this will work

Comment: ya Abishek thanks its working and here my days and months also locked but i dont wanna lock my months and days i need to lock only years can you help for this

Comment: use this one also [pickerView setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];

Comment: i used ur code but am unable to show the previous months and time also displaying i dont wanna time